# Android Studio: Failed to resolve: com.linkedin.android.litr:litr:1.1.0 while using cloudinary in my android app

Tags: android-studio, gradle, build.gradle, androidx, cloudinary

I am building the android app that uses Cloudinary to upload images and videos. I am using AndroidX for both frontend and backend. I have all the related dependencies such as `implementation 'com.cloudinary:cloudinary-android:1.30.0'` and `implementation 'com.linkedin.android.litr:litr:1.1.0'`, but on building the gradle I am getting the following error:

```
Failed to resolve: com.linkedin.android.litr:litr:1.1.0
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app

Failed to resolve: com.linkedin.android.litr:litr:1.1.0
<a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
Affected Modules: <a href="openFile:D:/VU/CS619/BC180405965/ePharmacy/app/build.gradle">app</a>
```

and upon running the app, I get the following error:

```
1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.linkedin.android.litr:litr:1.1.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/linkedin/android/litr/litr/1.1.0/litr-1.1.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/linkedin/android/litr/litr/1.1.0/litr-1.1.0.pom
       - https://www.jitpack.io/com/linkedin/android/litr/litr/1.1.0/litr-1.1.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :app
         project :app > com.cloudinary:cloudinary-android:1.30.0 > com.cloudinary:cloudinary-android-preprocess:1.30.0

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================
```

Is there anything that I am missing or doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

***try to type this line in the build.grade(project)***

```
repositories { 
maven{ 
url "https://maven.google.com"
} }
```